# Cannot change theme except via reboot

Tags: unity, themes

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10, unity, x64. Also have an nVIDIA GPU (Optimus 555M) if that's at all relevant for this issue.

I'm not sure if I'm missing anything, but I cannot seem to reliably change the theme - if I use unity-tweal-tool, gnome-tweak-tool or ubuntu-tweak, none work.

None of the following change the theme in either tool:
Selecting a theme
Double clicking a theme
unity --replace after changing a theme
compiz --replace after changing a theme

The only way I can seem to change theme is to select a new theme, close unity-tweak-tool, re-open unity-tweak-tool, if the theme option has stuck with the one I've selected reboot the computer - if not re-select it and repeat til it sticks, then reboot.

To my knowledge, just selecting a theme in either tool should auto apply it so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - any ideas?

**Edit:** So I changed the environment to Cinnamon and I can change themes there - so it seems to be something to do with Unity I guess?

Comment: Which theme are you talking about? The GTK theme or the window manager theme?

Comment: Either theme - nothing applies (Icons, window theme, GTK theme) until a reboot

Comment: Read Comments below here on following page: [Things/Tweaks To Do After Install Of Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic/14.04 Trusty](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/04/thingstweaks-to-do-after-install-of.html). So it might be possible that it's due to your Graphics Card itself or root cause is Drivers of your card. Can't judge from this end. This info may be help you.